# Mathematical Epidemiology Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-modeling, biology

I'm looking for a good Textbook for learning Mathematical Epidemiology. Something that I could read through and use as a future reference book.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Why not to go to Amazon and type "mathematical epidemiology" in the search box?

Answer (score 2):

What I have read and seen myself before related to epidemiology and infectious diseases, you can take a look at section one of chapter 11 of the book *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems and an Introduction to Chaos* written by *Hirsch, Smale and Devaney*. But in general there is a book from Springer called exactly *Mathematical Epidemiology* written by *Brauer et al.*

There is a dictionary type book at google book called *Biostatistical Genetics and Genetic Epidemiology*, for Genetic Epidemiology you can use it as a reference to concepts and terminologies.

Comment: This [Amazon link](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Epidemiology-Lecture-Notes-Mathematics/dp/3540789103) points to the Springer book by Brauer et al.

Comment: @ArnieDris good, but I already have access to Springer, you may want to tell it to User112358 as your suggestion to how prepare this book.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an analysis approach:
"Mathematical Models in Population Biology and Epidemiology" written by two world class experts in the field is a classic.

If you're looking for an statistical approach:
"Epidemiology - Study Design and Data Analysis" is quite popular for good reason.

Good luck.